# Error running flake8

Tags: python, flake8

I recently tried to install Flake8 for Python3 and since then I'm getting the following error message:

```
/Users/dorsam/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:159 [Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycodestyle.py:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/dorsam/.atom/packages/linter-flake8/node_modules/sb-exec/lib/index.js:56:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:554:12)
```

Comment: https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/728

Answer (score 1):

Look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> Support of nested sets and set operations as in Unicode Technical
>   Standard #18 might be added in the future. This would change the
>   syntax, so to facilitate this change a FutureWarning will be raised in
>   ambiguous cases for the time being. That includes sets starting with a
>   literal '[' or containing literal character sequences '--', '&&',
>   '~~', and '||'. To avoid a warning escape them with a backslash.